# Persistently or aggressively enabling Battery Saver

Tags: battery-life, stock-android

I love the Battery Saver feature. When I'm travelling or in other situations where reliable communication is more important than user experience, I want to always have it enabled, sometimes for days at a time.

However, Android automatically turns it off after the phone has been charged, requiring me to remember to go in and re-enable it after unplugging my phone. I occasionally forget.

Is there any way (including via third-party apps, excluding via rooting or jailbreaking the device) for me to automatically or persistently enable the Battery Saver, aside from the system's built-in options to enable it at 15% or 5% charge remaining? Alternatively, is there a way to leave it on indefinitely, or a way to have it automatically activate earlier (such as at 50% charge), or a way to activate it based on a schedule?

If there's no user-accessible way to do this yet, I would also be interested in knowing if there are any mechanisms in the operating system (URL schemes, framework APIs, relevant permission settings) that could potentially be used to control Battery Saver.

Comment: [Corresponding question for iOS (I use both), if anybody is curious.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/243683/1674)

Comment: Quick thought: check our [automation tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info). One of those apps might be capable of it. My first check would be if [Tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) can do that. The trigger is clear (when you disconnect the charger). Just not sure whether there's a plugin to deal with the battery saver.

Comment: @izzy: Yes, thanks. When I wrote earlier comment ( now deleted), this feature wasn't​ there  .Set myself a reminder on the app to check possibility and it reminded me today !

Comment: @beeshyams, nice workaround but as Izzy had suggested, with Tasker you could define the specific battery saving features  (e.g turning off gps, dimming light, disabling vibration etc) as a task then the profiles as battery level and disconnection from charger

Comment: @xavier_fakerat: me no Tasker :). Found it difficult to learn and switched to Macrodroid every since. I haven't yet needed to look for alternatives. You could add an alternative using Tasker, if it works for *non rooted* devices

Comment: @beeshyams, nowadays its not as tough as it was on first day of using it. Made use of online tutorials, now I realize the power locked inside Tasker and made very intersting projects and apps too with tasker. The useguide its pretty easy to learn trust me. One day you will see. :). However macrodroid is very user friendly and very time saving so its a big nod !

Answer (score 1):

[automation](/questions/tagged/automation) is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn.

Macrodroid along with other applications like Wakelock Detector have made this possible for **non rooted device** using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to grant `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission to the app

Following actions are possible (quoting developer's post in the forums, accessible from within the app (10/01/17)

> Battery Saver
>
> Location Mode
>
> NFC Enable/Disable

You need to set up `adb` on your laptop

Once you have a working adb connection, you need to run the following command from the command line/terminal on your computer:

```
adb shell pm grant com.arlosoft.macrodroid android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

---

Your macro would look like this

**Macro :** Toggle Battery Saver (name of macro as example)

**Trigger:** Empty Trigger

**Action**: Battery Saver  → Toggle

**Constraints:** Leave blank

Once you save the macro, go to widget drawer of Macrodroid and drag the shortcut widget to your home screen, and assign to the widget the macro you have created. Press  widget to toggle Battery Saver manually

Coming to your other requirement of activating Battery Saver at user defined percentage or on full charge, create another macro

**Macro :**  Battery Saver on full charge or when I want (name of macro as example)

**Trigger:**

1. Battery Level → increases to 100 % ( full charge )
2. Battery Level → decreases to 50 % ( user defined limit )

**Action**: Battery Saver → on

**Constraints:** Leave blank

My device is rooted, so can't verify `adb` command but from user response it works and I had used similar command for Wake Lock Detector when my device was not rooted

Comment: In the second macro, you could add trigger of *Power disconnected* also if you wish.  Triggers work in logical *OR*. Though with the *on demand* toggle of first macro and controlled activation in second macro, one is pretty much covered